# Web scraping with Python - how to parse tables

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to parse table from https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10 with BeautifulSoup and make pandas DataFrame?
My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
table = soup.find_all("table")
for each_table in table:
 for row in each_table.find_all('tr'):
  for cell in row.find_all("td"):
   print(cell.text)
```

I try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tbl = soup.find("table", {"id": "MainContent_dataGridView1"})

data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
print(data_frame)
```

But it says:

```
"ValueError: No tables found"
```

Comment: Does your `page.content` have the right table fields in it? Some pages need to be either rendered in browser or have the correct request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only a table with id="transparence_t"

So:

```
tbl = soup.find("table", {"id": "transparence_t"})
data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
print(data_frame)
```

It returns to me a 698x6 dataframe

Comment: When I put this in my code output was like this: <td class="range81050668_81050680">
    55.2
</td>
<td>
    0.9
</td>
<td>
    243
</td>
<td>
    0
</td>
<td>
    Да
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    Брянский гос. техн. ун-т.
</td>
<td>
    62.4
</td>
<td>
    2.4
</td>
<td>
    646
</td>
<td>
    0 And how you make dataframe?

Comment: you have to  write also the last 2 lines of your code. I edit the answer

Comment: Oh! Thank you! But if I want to print all data what should I do?

Comment: print where? in the console? cause you'll always see a fraction of the total dataframe in the console, but your dataframe is homever complete. if you export for example it in a csv file you could access all of it in excel. you can google how to do it or check some stackoverflow questions about it

Comment: Excel shows me this: 0,"–Р–і—Л–≥–µ–є—Б–Ї–Є–є –≥–Њ—Б. —Г–љ-—В., –≥. –Ь–∞–є–Ї–Њ–њ",60.5,-1.7,494,1,–Э–µ—В

Comment: how you exported it? show me the code. btw you can use this data_frame.to_excel("output.xlsx") or dataframe.to_csv() function