# Parsing table to csv Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I need to parse table from https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tbl = soup.find("table", {"id": "transparence_t"})

data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
data_frame.to_csv('hseparser.csv')
```

I parse it, but data are on A1 to A699 cell. I need smash data to different cells. Please help me!

Comment: Everything is in russian. Could you post the desired the result

Comment: The data is arranged in the tags <tr> and  <td> perfectly, You can easily run a `for` loop and arrange the data in DF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scrapping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181538/web-scrapping-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `read_html`already reads all the tables from the given url and returns a list of tables. You don't have to explicitly use `BeautifulSoup` package.

```py
>>> url = 'https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10'
>>> df = pd.read_html(url)
>>> len(df)
2
>>> df[0].head()
                                                   0                                                  1
0                                             Регион  Все  Алтайский край  Амурская область  Арханге...
1                                           Тип вуза  Все  Государственный  Головной  Филиал  Негосу...
2  Вузы с набором  больше  меньше  человек на бюд...  Вузы с набором  больше  меньше  человек на бюд...
>>> df[1].head()
                                                 Вуз  Качество приема на основании среднего балла ЕГЭ зачисленных на бюджетные места 2019  ...  Из них: без экзаменов  Ср.балл рассчитан с вычетом баллов за И.Д.?
0                   Адыгейский гос. ун-т., г. Майкоп                                               60.5                                    ...                      1                                          Нет
1  Азово-Черноморский инженерный ин-т. - филиал Д...                                               45.5                                    ...                      0                                          Нет
2   Академия труда и социальных отношений, г. Москва                                               77.8                                    ...                      0                                           Да
3          Алтайский гос. аграрный ун-т., г. Барнаул                                               54.7                                    ...                      0                                          Нет
4  Алтайский гос. гуманитарно-педагогический ун-т...                                               59.7                                    ...                      0                                           Да

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Saving this dataframe to csv will have all the data in different cells.

Comment: Just a advice : Better not save it as CSV, some other separator, Looks like there are commas in first columns.

Comment: Not work it says: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]